# How to run less compiler from php on windows

Tags: php, shell, less

I have this script in a file, this compiles a LESS file into a CSS file, it works perfectly from the GIT BASH. 
I need to run it from a php script (i want to recompile LESS with every reload of a page).

I am sort of stuck, since the functions `exec()`, resp. `shell_exec()`, simply said, do not execute the script in the file, they are just returning `NULL`.

I have windows, php5.4.

```
#!/bin/bash

lessc bootstrap.less gfx/compiled.css
```

**EDIT:**

**How did I solve it**

I had to manage to run a command `lessc`through windows cmd, not any other tool (like git bash).

- I had already had LESS installed through `npm`
- I also had put a path
  to the less node compiler residing in a folder `less/lessc` into the `windows PATH` (by now still working only in git bash, not win cmd)
- I run a command `npm install -g less` this installed less somehow globally, when the instalation was done, it echoed a path `%userdir%/AppData/Roaming/npm`, where has
  resided an important file `lessc.cmd`; a path to this file I added into the windows `PATH` and even though I was not able to run the above script like so `shell_exec('folder/script')` I wrote the command directly `shell_exec('lessc bootstrap.less bootstrap.css')` and t worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a less-compiler that is build in php!

For example: http://leafo.net/lessphp/

```
require "lessc.inc.php";

$less = new lessc;
$less->compileFile("bootstrap.less","gfx/compiled.css");
```

Comment: This option is not useful for me, since it did not compiled LESS content in files, which I imported through @import LESS rule, albeit this tool is handy for simple uses.

Comment: lessphp can handle the @import-command.
If it dont work at your application please write a Issue on their github-page!

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows local development i recommend using Koala - http://koala-app.com/
Koala will automatically convert your LESS to CSS for you anytime the file changes.